# Too much space between chapter title and content

Tags: class-options

I'm a LaTeX newbie and my someone on my university has made a custom LaTeX class, and I'm using it to make a dissertation.

However, the space between the chapter title and the content is way too much. I tried go looking on the `.cls` file to change it, but no luck since I don't know much.

What should I look on the class files to change it, or a way to override that setting on my document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Looking  into my magic chrystal ball: Unclear -- I see nothing -- your class is hidden behind fog and filthy air ;-)  Please provide more information. Side note: Custom template/classes are most times bad

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I asked about `possible` ways that I can change the spacing... Don't know how to be more specific without posting the whole class here

Comment: Well, is there a `\LoadClass{book}` command in your 'class' ? That would simplify the whole issue

Comment: `\LoadClass{report}`

Comment: You can provide a link to your class file.

Comment: @SomethingBrandNewAwful: Ok, it's most likely the standard `\chapter` settings from `report` (unless your class redefines `\@makechapterhead`) -- do not post `report.cls`. Provide link as Harish asked you already!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it actually redefined `\@makechapterhead`, I figured it out now :D

Comment: @SomethingBrandNewAwful: Ok, it's something like `\vspace*{50\p@}%` perhaps.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer posted my result as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from the comments I found it, the class redefined `@makechapterhead` and I had to change `\vspace`

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 {%
 %  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1.7pt}\\\par
 \normalfont\ABNTchaptersize\ABNTchapterfont%
 \espaco{simples}%
 \vspace*{5pt}%
 \noindent%
 \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
   \parbox[t]{2ex}{\thechapter}%
   \parbox[t]{\textwidth-4ex-1ex}%
    {\interlinepenalty\@M\raggedright%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{ABNTcapchap}}%
      {\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
      {#1}
  }%
\vspace*{0cm}
}\\[2pt]%
\vspace{10pt}%
}%
}
```